# Why are german restaurants so underwhelming in the United States?

Tags: german-cuisine

French, Italian, Korean, Japenese, all good foods with awesome representation in the United States.  Why is there so little, if at all, Germany food in the United States?

All the german establishments i'm able to find are low to mid tier cuisine, at best.

Comment: What part of the US are you in... because the US is huge... Perhaps you could write your question in a more constructive way? Right now it looks like a rant. We don't know what you mean by "German food", what you're expecting, why you think this is the case... I'm not sure if this question is on topic but, as written, you're not doing yourself any favors.

Comment: What do you consider "low to mid tier", please? Or the other way round - what are you looking for?

Comment: @Stephie check out the "examples" provided below.  The quality and presentation looks like the chef was classically trained at a diner and these are major internationalist cities brimming with "foodies".

Comment: But what **foods** are you looking for? If Americans don't know German food outside of brats and schnitzel, it's going to be unlikely to find the food you're talking about. I've always thought of German food as home-y... not fancy like French cuisine.

Comment: @Catija Somewhere, anywhere, with classically trained chefs or innovative representations of German Cuisine.  I've seen Mexican Food Trucks in LA with more disruptive power than the sum total of all German restaurants i've seen in the US.

Comment: That still doesn't tell us anything. I've never heard someone say "I want modern German food"... I hear people say - "Want a bratwurst?" and "I could really use some schnitzel and spaetzle".

Comment: @Catija "I've never heard someone say 'I want modern German food' ", so you agree with me.  You've never heard it because it doesn't exist.

Comment: ... but you haven't shown that it **actually** exists at all. @Stephie have you any clue what it is?

Comment: @Catija are you asking me to find examples of something that I claim does not exist?

Comment: It's a bit silly to ask why there aren't any ground-breaking German restaurants in the US if there aren't any on the planet... If you can't show that they exist in Germany, I'm not sure what you're looking for. I find American German food to generally fit into the category of "nostalgic food"... it's not designed to be earth-shattering.

Comment: @Catija lol, well why aren't there any ground-breaking german restaurants on planet earth then?

Comment: That's really not a question that's on topic here.

Comment: If you're looking for modern, innovative German-ish creations, then you shouldn't be asking about German restaurants, which are going to tend to serve more traditional cuisine.

Comment: This would be a good question if you elaborated further and narrowed the scope. Since I can only comment as this is on hold... In post WWII US, you didn't advertise if you were certain nationalities (such as German or Japanese), even if you were a US citizen. So I think German ethnic foods outside the home or local ethnic community became uncommon. Popular cuisine in recent decades is primarily driven by TV programming. Back in the French Chef days, a German or Japanese cooking show would have been unpopular at best.

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic, but anyway my favorite German restaurant is [*Teske's Germania*](http://teskes-germania.com/). I could even ask for something not on the menu with no problem.

Comment: See [chat] (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36481589#36481589) for my five cents on what classifies modern German food. Probably equally hard to find it as "modern US food". (Note the problem here? What exactly would be "US food"? You have lots of regional cuisines, partly thanks to immigrants from all over the world, and so does Germany. And most other countries, btw.)

Comment: @user3169 Interesting ideas regarding attitudes toward German food. But doesn't hold up when discussing Japanese food. *And* ...Teske's Germania? : ok, point #1, it's in a city that *doesn't matter*.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that largely depends on what portion of the country you reside in.  In areas more strongly influenced by Germanic and Scandinavian immigrants (upper Midwest), German restaurants abound and even in eateries that aren't specifically "German," you get regular offerings like Bratwurst, which is a mainstay at Milwaukee Brewer and Green Bay Packer games, for instance.

[The world's largest brat fest](http://www.bratfest.com/)

[The five best German Restaurants in Milwaukee](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g60097-c21-Milwaukee_Wisconsin.html)

[10 Old-Fashioned German Restaurants To Try in NYC](http://ny.eater.com/2015/9/16/9340223/best-german-restaurants-nyc-oktoberfest)

[The 15 Best Places For German Food In Dallas](https://foursquare.com/top-places/dallas/best-places-german-food)

Comment: Yeah but that's Milwaukee, i'm talking about cities that actually matter like LA, San Fran, NY, etc.

Comment: @easymoden00b - "Cities that matter."  LOL.  They can't matter that much if you can't even find a decent German eatery there, now, can they?  FYI, when I did the Google for the Milwaukee list link, NYC popped up near the top of the results that came back.  I'll edit, accordingly.

Comment: top 10 german restaurants in New York City, salad looks like it came from the grocery store. The other list for Dallas includes **sonic the fast food chain**. Nice examples there mate

Comment: @easymoden00b It's already been pointed out that this site is not a good place for rants, and some kinds of judgments can come across that way. Please be respectful.

Comment: @easymoden00b - "Salad looks like it came from a grocery store" - German food = salads, to you?  I wasn't expecting much from Dallas, either, but there are at least a couple actual German eateries, which disputes your claim of no actual German food in the entire USA.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet No, german food isn't salad to me.  Thank you for proving my point.  These places do not have classically trained chefs, nor do I think they'd even survive being sold out of a food truck in trendier areas of large cities, and these are supposed *top examples*.  Sure they exist, but they aren't impressive.

Comment: @easymoden00b - you must not be looking very hard.  They have a thing called "Google," you know - "classically trained German chef" - https://www.parkrestaurant.com/ Since when did having good food or representation rely on having a "classically trained chef" in that cuisine? 99.9% of the Korean food does NOT have such a cook in the kitchen, yet you seem to think it is well-represented.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet your most recent example looks generic, at best.  No innovation, nothing next level, not even close.

Comment: @easymoden00b - Sounds like you're not actually looking for a German restaurant, if you're looking for some sort of innovation fusion-food. "They don't even have a classically trained chef"  I showed you one.  If your main purpose was to whine about German food in the USA instead of actually asking about if any exists, then you probably shouldn't post it as a question.

Comment: "cities that actually matter"?  Really, that is a good way to get into a mode where no posts you make will be well received.  Also, with a little research, on would likely find that US cuisine is heavily influenced by German heritage and, with American influence, enough of us would just classify German cooking as home cooking.  Other than that we think of sausage = German = cook at home.